# Background Color Assistance

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason I was working on a basic `pygame` project and my background appears to be black, however I specified it as white. Please assist if possible.

Here is the code (by the way, this is PYGAME in python):

```html
import pygame
pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
red=(255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither')

gameExit=False

lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x -= 10

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x +=10

gameDisplay.fill(white)
pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black,[lead_x,lead_y,10,100])
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that your drawing code is outside of the while loop. Indent it by one tab and it should work, so, like this:

```html
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x -= 10

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x +=10

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black,[lead_x,lead_y,10,100])
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.Python's syntax is quite annoying,I must say.